# How can I change screen timeout based on whether my phone is/not charging?

Tags: charging, screen

I'd like my screen to stay lit while charging but have a timeout when just on battery. Is ther any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried checking in your system settings?

Comment: Yes, double checked, not there on galaxy s3 running ICS

Comment: Maybe that needs to get back to android so they can put that in the next release. Gingerbread has it, so should phones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) you can automate this to have different screen time-out values depending whether or not your phone is connected to a power source:

1. Create a new Profile and name it "Screen Timeout".
2. For Context select `State` -> `Power` -> `Power`.
3. Select "Any" for source and press the OK button.
4. Tap "New Task", name it "Increase Timeout" and tap the "OK" button.
5. Tap the `+` button to add a new Action, select `Display` category, and then `Display Timeout` action.
6. Drag the sliders for "Secs", "Mins" or "Hours" to your desired values for when the phone is connected to a power source.
7. Tap the "OK" button, and then tap it again.
8. Long-press the "Increase Timeout" action and select `Add Exit Task` option.
9. Tap "New Task", name it "Decrease Timeout" and tap the "OK" button.
10. Tap the `+` button to add a new Action, select `Display` category, and then `Display Timeout` action.
11. Drag the sliders for "Secs", "Mins" or "Hours" to your desired values for when the phone is running on battery.
12. Tap the "OK" button, and then tap it again.
13. Ensure the Tasker is enabled by toggling it ON (switch at bottom-right corner) and then tap the "OK" button.

You should be all set.  If you want to get fancy, you can add actions to both tasks to display toast messages.

Answer (score 6):

There's an option to keep your screen lit while charging, try:

`Settings -> Developer Options -> Stay Awake`

Comment: I've triple checked, developer options doesn't have a stay awake setting. IIRC my wildfire had it, so I'm v surprised. Maybe they don't want to encourage screen burn?

Comment: I see from your comment that you use Galaxy S3, that device has a HUGE screen and I wouldn't be surprised if Samsung removed that feature (I know the S2 have it).

Comment: I noticed using the phone reduces the rate it charges so ur probs  right. I wish they'd asked me first!!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try any power widget for eg. like this [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.abraxas.powerwidget.free&feature=search_result).

You can place the widget on your home screen and use the "always on" toggle to keep your phone always on during charging.

Comment: It's not the solution... he wants automated solution.

Comment: "Always ON" keeps screen always ON even when device is on battery.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) and add it's toggle widget `Stay Awake` on homescreen. Just, turn it ON and your screen will never timeout as long as the device is under voltage.

Comment: Dead link.  Even google's own links to the google play store don't work.